# WebRTC: what happens if both peers send an offer?

Tags: webrtc, sdp

Usually, one of the peers creates an offer while the other one answers it. 
What happens if both peers try to set up connections by creating an offer at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of these peers are sending 'offer' and noone is awaiting for the 'answer', then connection won't be established.

Comment: what if both of them are waiting for answer? What I mean, both of them have the code to get an answer

Comment: If both of them sent and 'offer' and then switched to waiting for an 'answer', then someone of them might catch offer before another one. And in that case they will able to establish connection.